# Why does this async method lock up the user interface?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using the following code to read all the images on a network drive and poplate an `ImageControl` with each, and then display them on the screen.

The problem I'm having is that regardless of making `PopulateImages()` an `async` method, and and running `Task.WaitAll` the user interface is still locked up until all the images render.

Am I doing the `async/await` incorrectly? What do I need to do to resolve this?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) => PopulateImages();
}

private async void PopulateImages()
{
    string StartDirectory = @"//path/to/network/folder";

    Task.WaitAll(Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(StartDirectory)
        .Select(filename => Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Bitmap resizedImage;
            using (var sourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var destinationStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);

                    resizedImage = ResizeImage(new Bitmap(destinationStream), 96, 96);
                }
            }

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                var imgControl = new ImageControl(filename, resizedImage);

                stackpanelContainer.Children.Add(imgControl);
            }));
        })).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` <-----

Comment: `PopulateImages` is `async` but has no `await`.  This should generate a warning.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using `Task.Run` here, as the only thing that you're running in another thread is the code that you want to run in the UI thread, forcing you to needlessly use the `Dispatcher`, which you shouldn't be touching at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `Task.WaitAll` - that *blocks* until all the tasks have completed.

Instead, you should use [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall), which returns a `Task` which will itself complete when all the other tasks have completed. You can then await that.

```
await Task.WhenAll(...);
```

Although to be honest, unless you need to do anything when the tasks have all completed, you don't need to wait for them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering to the `Loaded` event, consider overriding [`FrameworkElement.OnInitialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized(v=vs.110).aspx) method. That way, you can `await` on `PopulateImage`, save the `Task.WaitAll` and possibly remove the need to use `Task.Run`, if your `ResizeImage` isn't too CPU heavy:

```
public override async void OnInitialized()
{
    await PopulateImages();
    base.OnInitialized();
}

private async Task PopulateImages()
{
   string StartDirectory = @"//path/to/network/folder";

   Directory.EnumerateFiles(StartDirectory)
                   .Select(filename => async () =>
                   {
                       Bitmap resizedImage;
                       using (var sourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                       using (var destinationStream = new MemoryStream())
                       {
                           await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);

                           resizedImage = ResizeImage(new Bitmap(destinationStream), 96, 96);
                       }
                   }

                   var imgControl = new ImageControl(filename, resizedImage);

             stackpanelContainer.Children.Add(imgControl);

}
```